# Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a region and let $f,g$ meromorphic functions in $U$, $f(p)=g(p)$ for all $p\in P\subseteq U$. Can I say that $f=g$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a region and let $f,g$ meromorphic functions in $U$. Suppose that there exist a set $P\subseteq U$ with a acumulation point in $U$ with $f(p)=g(p)$ for all $p\in P$.

**Can I say that $f=g$?**

[*I was tempted to use the principle of identity but remembered that this is valid for holomorphic functions but I do not know if there is a similar result for meromorphic functions.*]

**If $f$  is an essential singularity in $U$. Can I say that $f=g$?**

Comment: You could say that the two are equal on $U$ minus the union of the sets of singularities of $f,g$ by using the identity principle. You can't do better I think since $f$ may have singularities where $g$ is holomorphic (non-equal sets of singularities) and vice versa.

Comment: I don't think $f$ having singularity where $g$ is holomorphic can occur. Please see my answer.

Comment: What if the accumulation point is precisely a pole?

Comment: @ShubhodipMondal is correct - my initial thought was also correct but you need to go further from that in order to conclude they are exactly equivalent. Their answer is a correct, although there are some details you should fill in (you need to show that the accumulation point can not be a pole, for example).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is Yes.

Note that all meromorphic functions can be written as $f/g$ where $f$ and $g$ are analytic functions. (why?)  So say you have $f_1 (p)/g_1 (p) = f_2(p)/g_2(p)$ for $p \in P$. Then $f_1(p) g_2 (p) = g_1(p) f_2(p)$ for $p \in P$. But $P$ has a limit point. So $f_1 (z) g_2(z) = g_1(z) f_2(z)$ for all $z \in U$ by identity theorem. So $f_1/g_1 = f_2/g_2$.

Edit: Please note that if we define $g(z) = f_1(z) g_2(z) - g_1(z) f_2(z)$, then $g(z) $ is a holomiorphic function on $U$. So if its zero set has an accumulation point then it is identically zero. It doesn't matter if the accumulation point is a pole or whatever as long as it is in the domain $U$.
(Remember that the poles are contained in $U$, by the definition of meromorphic functions)

Edit 2: For essential singularities, consider the function $f(z) =e^{1/z}$ on the open unit disk. Consider the sequence $u_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi i n }$. Then $u_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and $f(u_n) = 1$. But $f$ is NOT equal to $1$.

Comment: What happens if $P$ has the accumulation point precisely at a pole?

Comment: Read the proof. It doesn't mater.

Comment: I already understood  I showed that a pole can not be accumulation point of $P$. Now, I want to know what happens if $f$ has an essential singularity, I think that the statement is false, so I'm trying to find a counterexample.

Comment: See my edit. I hope that answers all your questions.